# How to go to a different page from current in Django template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

```
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', predict_views.index, name = 'HomePage'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^Update_db/$', predict_views.Update_db, name = 'Update_db'),
    url(r'^compare/(?P<phone1_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<phone2_id>[0-9]+)/$',predict_views.Compare, name = 'Compare'),
    url(r'^predict/(?P<phone_id>[0-9]+)/$',predict_views.Predict, name = 'Predict'),
]
```

these are my url patterns in djano. I want to go to compare directly from predict which is not possible for me currently because :
when I go to predict the url is 127.0.0.1:8000/predict/1 now when i go to compare from predict the url becomes 127.0.0.1:8000/predict/1/compare/1/2 which is not the expected url .. my url should be 127.0.0.1:8000/compare/1/2

I have seen django docs there are some redirect methods but I do not understand them.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to show the way you are creating the link in your template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something tells me you are accidentally using relative urls. In your template, try the following:

```
<a href="{% url 'compare' phone1_id phone2_id %}">Compare Page</a>
```

Comment: I tried putting a "/" in front and it worked .. well thanks